# Evaluar detalle de Duplicados (SQl Server)

Tags: sql

necesito evaluar un detalle de registros duplicados ,triplicados ....
Donde los campos son Fecha ,Rut ,Hora ,Monto
la Hora seria el único campo distinto

Se debe mostrar los registros con diferencia de 5 minutos de un mismo Rut

agradezco la ayuda.

---

Select fecha,Rut,Monto from Log_cca
where fecha = '13/12/2022'
group by fecha,Rut,Monto
order by fecha,rut,monto

esta Query empecé a realizar lo que necesito

---

adjunto Ejemplo :
Estimado Ariel , gracias por contestar, adjunto un ejemplo de la data que obtuve con los Duplicados

| Fecha | Rut | Monto | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:15:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:16:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:18:00 |
| 103/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:36:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:15:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:16:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:18:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:36:00 |

Resultado a Mostrar

| Fecha | Rut | Monto | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:15:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:16:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-9 | 5.000 | 21:18:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:15:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:16:00 |
| 13/12/2022 | 1-8 | 3.000 | 21:18:00 |

Espero que sirva el Ejemplo

Comment: Hola Hugo. Bienvenido al sitio. Te invito a visitar el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), y leas acerca de [Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), sobre [cuáles temas puedes preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y [cuáles preguntas debes evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). No nos has mostrado lo que has intentado y no sabemos la estructura de tu base de datos, ni has dado ejemplos de lo que constituye un dato duplicado. Cuál es tu pregunta **específica**?

Comment: Estimado Ariel , gracias por contestar

Comment: No olvides mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Y como te lo han preguntado, indicá _cuál es tu pregunta __específica___.